# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

I get this error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

In this function:

```
   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    tableViewData.append(textField.text)
    textField.text = ""
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    // Reference to our app delegate

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    // Reference moc

    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("note", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Create instance of pur data model an initialize

    var newNote = Model(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Map our properties

    newNote.note = textField.text

    // Save our context

    contxt.save(nil)
    println(newNote)

    // navigate back to root vc

    //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    return true
}
```

and this line of code:

```
 var newNote = Model(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
```

Does someone have a solution for this error?
I use xCode 6.0.1. Programing language is Swift and the Simulator runs with iOS8 (iPhone 5s).

Answer (score 1):

`NSEntityDescription.entityForName("note", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)` returns an `NSEntityDescription?`. So it is optional and can be `nil`. When you force to unwrap it (with `!` operator) if it is `nil` then your program crashes. In order to avoid this you can `if-let` syntax. Here is how:

```
if let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("note", inManagedObjectContext: contxt) {
    // Do your stuff in here with entity. It is not nil.
}
```

However in Core Data cause of the entity become `nil` is maybe you spell the name "note" wrong. Check your xcdatamodel file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my problem was i didn't spell well the name.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when you unwrap an optional which contains `nil`. If that's the line causing the error, then it's the `en` variable set to `nil`, and you are trying to force unwrap it.

I cannot provide a reason for it to be `nil`, but I suggest to avoid using forced unwrapping (i.e. using the `!` operator), and rely on optional binding instead:

```
if let en = en {
    var newNote = Model(entity: en, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    // Map our properties

    newNote.note = textField.text

    // Save our context

    contxt.save(nil)
    println(newNote)
}
```

That solves the exception. You should investigate on why `en` is `nil` though.